# php array keys problem

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$rt1 = array
(
  'some_value1' => 'xyz1',
  'some_value2' => 'xyz2',
  'value_1#30'=>array('0'=>1),
  'value_2#30'=>array('0'=>2),
  'value_3#30'=>array('0'=>3),
  'value_1#31'=>array('0'=>4),
  'value_2#31'=>array('0'=>5),
  'value_3#31'=>array('0'=>6),
  'some_value3' => 'xyz3',
  'some_value4' => 'xyz4',
);


$array_30 = array
(
'0'=>1,
1=>'2',
2=>'3'
);

$array_31 = array
(
'0'=>4,
'1'=>'5',
'2'=>'6'
);
```

I need to make it an array and insert the `array_30` and `array_31` into a DB.

Comment: please format your code with either enclosing in backticks \` or intending it with four spaces

Comment: Is it the real situation, I means your real code? please post the code itself..

Comment: How is this related to "key splitting"?

Comment: in your first array no deep value is a string, whereas in the second array value #2 and #3 are strings. do you have typos or is this intentional?

Comment: and even after editing your post there is a difference between the values of $rt1 and the result arrays - are they intentional?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($rt1 as $value){
   $rt2[] = $value['0'];
}
```

The question was updated, so here is an updated answer. Quick check, you should really try and update this to whatever more generic purpose you have, but as a proof of concept, a runnable example:

```
<?php   
$rt1 = array
(
  'some_value1' => 'xyz1',
  'some_value2' => 'xyz2',
  'value_1#30'=>array('0'=>1),
  'value_2#30'=>array('0'=>2),
  'value_3#30'=>array('0'=>3),
  'value_1#31'=>array('0'=>4),
  'value_2#31'=>array('0'=>5),
  'value_3#31'=>array('0'=>6),
  'some_value3' => 'xyz3',
  'some_value4' => 'xyz4',
);

$finalArrays = array();

foreach($rt1 as $key=>$value){
    if(is_array($value)){
       $array_name = "array_".substr($key,-2);
       ${$array_name}[] = $value['0'];
    }

}

var_dump($array_30);
var_dump($array_31);



?>
```

will output the two arrays with the numbers 1,2,3 and 4,5,6 respectivily

Comment: Hmm, question has changed a lot, above isn't your answer. You should do something with "if is_array" and $$value. I'll check if I can find some time for an answer

Answer (score 0):

i assume you want to join the values of each of the second-level arrays, in which case:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($rt1 as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        $result[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that this is your actual code, probably you will need to copy the array somewhere using `foreach` and afterwards create the new array as you wish:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
   $arr[$key] = 1;
}
```

Comment: was just a concept that what you want to do, take care to do not copy the value over value and get only the last value..

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Nanne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658711/php-array-keys-problem/4658741#4658741) (which reminded me of dynamically naming variables), this solution will work with every identifier after the `\#`, regardless of its length:

```
foreach ( $rt1 as $key => $value )
{
    if ( false == strpos($key, '#') ) // skip keys without #
    {
        continue;
    }       
            // the part after the # is our identity
    list(,$identity) = explode('#', $key); 
    ${'array_'.$identity}[] = $rt1[$key]['0'];  
}
```